# What is the meaning of " It's a bit of a no-brainer "

Tags: phrase-meaning

http://www.promo.cymru/use-captions-subtitles/

If you’re producing a video, **it’s a bit of a no-brainer** to use captions and subtitles, because:

What is the meaning of the phrase " it's a bit of a no-brainer " in the above context. What can be used instead of that phrase.

Comment: As @RonaldSole points out, this question is already answered with easy research elsewhere.  Please give us a more difficult challenge that can't be easily resolved with a simple online search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ***[no-brainer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/no%E2%80%93brainer)*** is:

> - a decision or choice that is very easy to make and requires very little thought. (M-W)

- It is just obvious  to use captions and subtitles.

Comment: I am reading a PDF " introduction to Linux Mint " . In that PDF there are these sentences:     "The software available to you on the repositories you use will always be stable and well tested, unless you change those repositories to the ones used by the testers (in which case congratulations, you've just become a tester). It's a bit of a no-brainer, really."        So does the last sentence mean "It's just obvious, really"?

Comment: @ARAM -      In this context they are saying, it is just very easy, really.

Comment: No, they aren't saying that it's easy, they are saying that you don't have to think about it (no brains necessary) or do anything, that the default is precisely what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "a no-brainer" refers to something that should be obvious. That's to say that it doesn't require any thought or endeavour to resolve.

If you googled it, you would find numerous explanations.

(www.yourdictionary.com)